# Does onTapGesture Hijack Events?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use `onTapGesture` but doing so makes it nearly impossible to access the list - if I remove `onTapGesture` it works perfectly

Here's what I'm working with:

```
struct NavPickerView: View {
    @State var selected: Int = -1
    @State var cities: [String] = ["New York", "San Diego", "Houston", "Boston"]
    @State var selectionStarted: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(selectionStarted ? "SELECTING" : "WAITING")")
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("Search for...")) {
                            Text("Select City").tag(-1)
                            ForEach(0..<cities.count) {
                                Text(verbatim: self.cities[$0]).tag($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture { self.selectionStarted = true }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Cities"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any way of running code when an item is selected without making the list nearly inaccessible?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems `.onAppear` is a better fit:

```swift
Form {
    Section {
        Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("Search for...")) {
            Text("Select City").tag(-1)
            ForEach(0..<cities.count) {
                Text(verbatim: self.cities[$0]).tag($0)
            }
            .onAppear { self.selectionStarted = true }
        }
    }
}
```